# Different colors for bars in BarChart depend on value

Tags: swift, ios-charts

How can I change the color of a single bar, dependent on its value, in a bar chart?
For example: I have five different values (= five different bars) in my bar chart. All bars that have a value less than 30 should be red, all bars between 30 and 70 orange, and all bars above 70 should be green.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In ios-charts, the colors of the bars are set in an array. If your dataset is called barChartDataset, for example, you would set the colors like this

```
barChartDataset.colors = [UIColor.red,UIColor.orange,UIColor.green,UIColor.black,UIColor.blue]
```

The bars will have these colors in this order and will repeat. So if you have 10 bars, you would have 2 red bars etc.

In your case, you just have to write a function to return the right color value, and attach it to the array. Reference the code below.

```
func setColor(value: Double) -> UIColor{

    if(value < 30){
        return UIColor.red
    }
    else if(value <= 70 && value >= 30){
        return UIColor.orange
    }
    else if(value > 70){
        return UIColor.green
    }

    else { //In case anything goes wrong
    return UIColor.black
    }
}
```

And then wherever you are setting the chart use

```
 barChartDataset.colors = [setColor(barOneValue),setColor(barTwoValue),setColor(barThreeValue),setColor(barFourValue),setColor(barFiveValue)]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Save my time!

Comment: By using above function it works, but it shows repeating colors in indicator below the graph... How it should be done like red color is low value, green color is high value.

Comment: Can you add an image as to what you mean by indicator?

Comment: Nice answer. Is it possible to change the legend accordingly? For example: red = bad value, yellow = normal, green = good value etc.

Answer (score 1):

Their API also comes with some predefined color templates you can use to set different colors for the data set. They include:

- ChartColorTemplates.liberty()
- ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
- ChartColorTemplates.pastel()
- ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
- ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()

You can use them this way :

```
chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
```

Reference : https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: How can I change the value of a single bar? For example green for the first one, red for the second one, etc...?

Comment: I have modified the answer

Answer (score -1):

In danielgindi charts the bar chart, bar color can be changed from "ChartColorTemplate.swift" file in the following code -

```
 @objc open class func material () -> [NSUIColor]
    {
        return [
            NSUIColor(red: 46/255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 113/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
            NSUIColor(red: 241/255.0, green: 196/255.0, blue: 15/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
            NSUIColor(red: 231/255.0, green: 76/255.0, blue: 60/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
            NSUIColor(red: 52/255.0, green: 152/255.0, blue: 219/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        ]
    }
```