# iOS Charts Bubble Chart Colors

Tags: ios, swift, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

How can I set specific colors for an individual bubble in an iOS Charts bubble chart dependent on its y-value? Just like it is shown in one of the screenshot on the iOS Charts GitHub site [here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/6704c21e680e831c3c07d0bebf2676f5e99a3d41/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d50416e64726f696443686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f627562626c6563686172742e706e67).
So all top level bubbles should be the same color, all middle ones another, etc...

I already tried to change the color like that:

```
chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.orange, UIColor.green]
```

But that only changes the color for every x value.

**Full Code**

That is my full code for setting the bubble chart:

```
func getDetailedAnalytics() {

    let currentTeacherDetailedAnalyticsUrl = TEACHER_DETAILED_ANALYTICS_URL + currentTeacherCourseId

    Alamofire.request(currentTeacherDetailedAnalyticsUrl).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            let firstDateValue = dict["0"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let secondDateValue = dict["1"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let thirdDateValue = dict["2"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let fourthDateValue = dict["3"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let fifthDateValue = dict["4"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            let firstDateLow = firstDateValue?["numberValuesUnder50"] as! Int
            let firstDateMiddle = firstDateValue?["numberValuesInMiddle"] as! Int
            let firstDateHigh = firstDateValue?["numberValuesOver75"] as! Int

            let secondDateLow = secondDateValue?["numberValuesUnder50"] as! Int
            let secondDateMiddle = secondDateValue?["numberValuesInMiddle"] as! Int
            let secondDateHigh = secondDateValue?["numberValuesOver75"] as! Int

            let thirdDateLow = thirdDateValue?["numberValuesUnder50"] as! Int
            let thirdDateMiddle = thirdDateValue?["numberValuesInMiddle"] as! Int
            let thirdDateHigh = thirdDateValue?["numberValuesOver75"] as! Int

            let fourthDateLow = fourthDateValue?["numberValuesUnder50"] as! Int
            let fourthDateMiddle = fourthDateValue?["numberValuesInMiddle"] as! Int
            let fourthDateHigh = fourthDateValue?["numberValuesOver75"] as! Int

            let fifthDateLow = fifthDateValue?["numberValuesUnder50"] as! Int
            let fifthDateMiddle = fifthDateValue?["numberValuesInMiddle"] as! Int
            let fifthDateHigh = fifthDateValue?["numberValuesOver75"] as! Int

            self.analyticsData = [25, 62, 88, 25, 62, 88, 25, 62, 88, 25, 62, 88, 25, 62, 88]
    self.analyticsAmountsData = [firstDateLow, firstDateMiddle, firstDateHigh, secondDateLow, secondDateMiddle, secondDateHigh, thirdDateLow, thirdDateMiddle, thirdDateHigh, fourthDateLow, fourthDateMiddle, fourthDateHigh, fifthDateLow, fifthDateMiddle, fifthDateHigh]
    self.setBubbleChart(dataPoints: self.dateBubble, values: self.analyticsData, amounts: self.analyticsAmountsData)
        }
    }
}

func setBubbleChart(dataPoints: [Int], values: [Int], amounts: [Int]) {

    var dataEntries: [BubbleChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BubbleChartDataEntry(x: Double(dataPoints[i]), y: Double(values[i]), size: (CGFloat(amounts[i])))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let format = NumberFormatter()
    format.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
    format.zeroSymbol = ""
    let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)

    let chartDataSet = BubbleChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    let chartData = BubbleChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

    bubbleView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    bubbleView.scaleXEnabled = false
    bubbleView.scaleYEnabled = false
    bubbleView.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
    bubbleView.highlightPerDragEnabled = false

    let firstLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Below 50", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
    let secondLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Between 50 and 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
    let thirdLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Over 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)

    bubbleView.chartDescription = nil
    bubbleView.legend.entries = [firstLegend, secondLegend, thirdLegend]
    bubbleView.data = chartData

    bubbleView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)

    let xAxis: XAxis = bubbleView.xAxis
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    xAxis.axisMaximum = 10

    let leftAxis: YAxis = bubbleView.leftAxis
    leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(2, force: true)
    leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100

    let rightAxis: YAxis = bubbleView.rightAxis
    rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
}
```

All bubbles with the value 25 should be the same color (e.g. red), all bubbles with the value 62 should be the same color (e.g. orange), and all bubbles with the value 88 should be the same color (e.g. green).

Comment: Your gonna need to show what you have already done and some code

Comment: @RyanM please look at the edit

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer over here: [Different colors for bars in BarChart depend on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436940/different-colors-for-bars-in-barchart-depend-on-value/40939517#40939517)

But essentially you need to write a custom function that returns a UIColor depending on the value.

```
func setColor(value: Double) -> UIColor{

if(value < 30){
    return UIColor.red
}
else if(value <= 70 && value >= 30){
    return UIColor.orange
}
else if(value > 70){
    return UIColor.green
}

else { //In case anything goes wrong
return UIColor.black
}
}
```

And then set the colors like this

```
chartDataSet.colors.append(setColor(dataValue))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This just changes the color per column and not per row

Comment: Can you show me the full code for how you are setting your bubble chart?